# Возможно ли пройти авторизацию с кодом на номер телефона selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, cookie

Мне нужно зайти на сайт wildberries parthers. Там проходить авторизация с кодом на номер телефона. Возможно ли как пройти авторизацию используя селениум после просто сохранить куки?